# Looping hml code using js, and use inthe html code js variables

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have a html code that I have to repeat many times, in those blocks of code , only 3 parts change,2  string and a link to an image.

My question is if I could use js loops to repeat the html code, changing these 3 parts using a js array or two different js variables  so I don't have to write the html 200 times.

Thanks.

This is the code html block, the 3 parts I want to change are, STRING1, STRING2 and IMAGE LINK.

```
<li class="item-thumbs span3 STRING1 ">
  <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="STRING2" href="IMAGE LINK">
</li>
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can! What did you try/what about it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlInsert = "",
    documentNode = document.getElementById('someDiv');

someArray.forEach( function( item, index ) {

    htmlInsert+= '<li class="item-thumbs span3' + item.STRING1 + '"> <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + item.STRING2 + '" href="' + item.STRING3 + '"></li>'

};

someDiv.innerHTML = htmlInsert;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < your_data.length; i++){
    html += '<li class="item-thumbs span3' + your_data[i].STRING1 + '"> <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + your_data[i].STRING2 + '" href="' + your_data[i].STRING3 + '"></li>';
}
console.log(html);  //this is what you want
```